# How i apply on backpressed() functionality in navigation drawer in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How to apply on backpressed() in navigation drawer layout with minimal SDK version 33

I apply it then it move to navigation drawer to fragment but when again pressed it doesn't exit the app

Please give me solution for minimum version is 33